# Publish will not push adovbs.inc to target File System destination (classic asp and IIS 7.5)

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-7.5, publish, server-side-includes

I have a classic ASP site on my Visual Studio 2012 development machine and I have noticed a strange behavior with **Publish**.

A file called **adovbs.inc** exists in a folder called **debug** within the root of the site. Quite a few files on the (development) site reference this without problem with this syntax:

```
<!--#include file="../debug/adovbs.inc" -->
```

After a "successful" Publish operation, I note that the adovbs.inc file did **not** in-fact get copied to the target location (on the production machine) and hence I get:

```
The include file '../debug/adovbs.inc' was
not found.
```

I wonder if the filetype .inc could be the problem? Most server-side include files have filetypes of .asp in my site. Is there another "knob to turn" somewhere in IIS 7.5?

After lots of frustration, I simply copied the file and pasted it with Windows Explorer and then the file was found at runtime.

Comment: Why are you using `adovbs.inc`? There is a better way [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) stored in your `global.asa` one reference no need for `#include` references whenever `ADODB` constants are used.

Comment: @Lankymart - but if this is going on to a web server somewhere, access to the TLB can't be guaranteed.

Comment: @Paul Why not? Doesn't need access to the TLB can use `uuid` to reference it doesn't need to use physical path. If that doesn't work then `ADODB` isn't installed so your screwed either way because `Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")` will fail to create component. Shouldn't be deploying it to a web server without MDAC in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use VS Publish website option for a classic asp site because there is nothing to compile, use the Copy website option instead, you can find it in the Website menu or right-click on the website in the solution explorer.

Comment: thanks; I can see how your suggestion makes sense but I have a "hybrid" site. Most of the site is classic ASP with VBscript on the webserver, server side includes, etc. Yet, the last round of enhancements were done with VB.Net and use ASP.NET 2.0. The result is a web "application" (i.e. "copy website" is not exposed as an option; only PUBLISH).

Comment: I take away a corallary lesson from your answer: there IS something to compile because I have a "hybrid" site and in VStudio2012 terms the project is a web app project - not a web site project. In short, the lesson I follow now is there is nothing "wrong" with copying the content. The "old fashioned way" worked just fine; I fail to see what is so great about the PUBLISH facility. Lots of complexity and hidden rules and gotcha's. Maybe some benefits but for "File System" deployment, I found nothing but headaches.

Comment: Just an idea, but maybe you could have 2 different projects in the same solution and deploy it separately ? copy one and publish the other